# How do I change font-family for my whole Extjs web app?

Tags: css, font-family, extjs6-classic

I'm working on Extjs 6.0.2. We were using Arial font in our app (I guess it was by default font from sencha). Now we want to change it to 'open-sans'. What do we have to change?

I tried to add:

```
.* ,.x-body , .x-panel-body-startPageItem, .x-panel-body-default {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

In *Project/packages/MyApp/sass/src/MyApp/view/MainView.scss*, but it changes fonts only on the landing page.

This works but I have to add all the classes one by one where I have to show this style like I added above `.x-panel-body-startPageItem,.x-panel-body-default`.

I also tried adding the following in *project/resources/css/MyApp.css*, but no use:

```
.* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
}
```

Comment: `* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
}` at the end of your sheet

Comment: Remove `.` before `*` and it should work like this `* { font-family: 'Open Sans' !important; }`

Comment: In project/resources/css/MyApp.css
Or 
here ->Project/packages/MyApp/sass/src/MyApp/view/MainView.scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
}
```

Use this:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
}
```

```
<p>something</p>
```

because `.*` doesn't work as you would expect, where just `*` targets everything.

Or you can as well use:

```
html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans' !important;
}
```